# Capturing keystrokes in a panel in java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events

I want to capture keystrokes when the focus in on a panel in java. What should i do?

I am using Netbeans as the IDE. I tried adding keyTyped event but it doesnot work.

Here goes my code

```
import com.lanadmin.Interface.ClientInterface;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.util.logging.Level;


public class RemoteViewer extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {


    public RemoteViewer() {
        initComponents();
        rdpanel.setFocusable(true);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        rdpanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        setFocusable(true);

        rdpanel.setToolTipText("Remote Desktop");
        rdpanel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                rdpanelMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                rdpanelMousePressed(evt);
            }
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                rdpanelMouseReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        rdpanel.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                rdpanelMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });
        rdpanel.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                rdpanelFocusGained(evt);
            }
        });
        rdpanel.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyPressed(evt);
            }
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyReleased(evt);
            }
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout rdpanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(rdpanel);
        rdpanel.setLayout(rdpanelLayout);
        rdpanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            rdpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 679, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        rdpanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            rdpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 626, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(rdpanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(rdpanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    private void rdpanelMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        double xScale = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / rdpanel.getWidth();
        double yScale = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / rdpanel.getHeight();
        try {
            String current = Login.handler.currentClientAddress.getHostAddress();
            ClientInterface client = (ClientInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://" + current + "/lan");
            client.mousemove((int) (evt.getX() * xScale), (int) (evt.getY() * yScale));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log2File.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            Log2File.fileHandler.flush();
        }
    }                                  
    private void rdpanelKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        System.out.println("keypressed");
    }                                  
    private void rdpanelKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        System.out.println("aaa");
    }                                
    private void rdpanelKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        System.out.println("keyreleased");
    }                                   
   private void rdpanelFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
        rdpanel.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
           @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyPressed(evt);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyReleased(evt);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                rdpanelKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
    }                                   
    public javax.swing.JPanel rdpanel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new FocusListener and a new KeyListener to the panel. If you only want the keystrokes captured when the panel is in focus, get the FocusListener's action to add the KeyListener and remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what you want is a KeyboardManager to install a KeyEventPostProcessor, or even an alternate dispatch for various components.  I had the same issues in a NB app as you did.

Here's the article I used: ([developer.com](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3463681))

I did this to capture enter key events from any control in a panel (to initiate "OK" button behavior automatically):

```
    KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    manager.addKeyEventPostProcessor(new EnterKeyListener());
```

And the listener:

```
    class EnterKeyListener implements KeyEventPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            //Activate the refresh button:
            fireSearch();
            return true;    //halt further processing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a possibly simpler solution see "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" answer about a default key here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688849/focus-navigation-in-keybinding

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to invoke [`setFocusable(true)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)), as discussed in [*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add `KeyListener` to your panel:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { … }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { … }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { … }
});
```

Handle event with the corresponding method.

As others precisely mentioned, you have to set `panel.setFocusable(true);` and, naturally, you ought to add this component to your frame (or other parent component).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could maybe also find help here: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html

Comment: Did you move the focus to that component, by clicking with your mouse? Still nothing?

Comment: Ok, removed that useless suggestion, but I'd suggest you take a look at the link and specifically ActionMap and InputMap there. Those might be what you are after.