# Focus navigation in keyBinding

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, focusmanager

In my form, when i press `ENTER` button in my keyboard, the `okAction()` method should be invoke (and invoke perfectly).

My problem is in focus state, When i fill the text fields and then press the `ENTER` button, the `okAction()` didn't invoked, because the focus is on the second text field (not on the panel).

How fix this problem?

```
public class T3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton cancelBtn, okBtn;
JLabel fNameLbl, lNameLbl, tempBtn;
JTextField fNameTf, lNameTf;

public T3() {
    add(createForm(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new T3();
        }
    });
}

public JPanel createForm() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "Button");
    panel.getActionMap().put("Button", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            okAction();
        }
    });

    okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
    okBtn.addActionListener(this);
    cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    tempBtn = new JLabel();
    fNameLbl = new JLabel("First Name");
    lNameLbl = new JLabel("Last Name");
    fNameTf = new JTextField(10);
    fNameTf.setName("FnTF");
    lNameTf = new JTextField(10);
    lNameTf.setName("LnTF");

    panel.add(fNameLbl);
    panel.add(fNameTf);
    panel.add(lNameLbl);
    panel.add(lNameTf);
    panel.add(okBtn);
    panel.add(cancelBtn);
    panel.add(tempBtn);

    panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 3, 2, 50, 10, 80, 60);
    return panel;
}

private void okAction() {
    if (fNameTf.getText().trim().length() != 0 && lNameTf.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
        System.out.println("Data saved");
    } else System.out.println("invalid data");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == okBtn) {
        okAction();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a default button for your GUI's JRootPane:

```
public T3() {

  //!! ..... etc...

  setVisible(true);
  getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okBtn);
}
```

In fact with a default button set, I don't see that you need to use key bindings.

Comment: Very Very Good, Thanks :D!